# C# DotLiquid NullReferenceException

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, c#-4.0, template-engine

I'm using DotLiquid on the latest SVN commit and trying the following "easy" code.

```
Template.NamingConvention = new CSharpNamingConvention();
Book selectedBook = (Book)this.booksList.SelectedObject;

string pathToTemplate = "..\\..\\..\\Resources\\templates\\white.html";
string res = "";

res = File.ReadAllText(pathToTemplate);

// Parse and compile the template
Template template = Template.Parse(res);
Console.WriteLine(template.RenderAndRethrowErrors(Hash.FromAnonymousObject(new { book = selectedBook })));
```

The error happens in the RenderAndRethrowErrors method.

Here is a stack trace:

at DotLiquid.Context.HandleError(Exception ex)

```
at DotLiquid.Block.<>c__DisplayClass1.<RenderAll>b__0(Object token)

   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)

   at DotLiquid.Block.RenderAll(List`1 list, Context context, StringBuilder result)

   at DotLiquid.Block.Render(Context context, StringBuilder result)

   at DotLiquid.Template.RenderInternal(Context context, Hash registers, IEnumerable`1 filters)

   at DotLiquid.Template.Render(Hash localVariables, IEnumerable`1 filters, Hash registers)

   at DotLiquid.Template.RenderAndRethrowErrors(Hash hash)

   at Collect_It_All.CIA_Main.booksList_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Documents\Dev\ezcollector\solution\Collect-It-All\CIA_Main.cs:line 298

   at BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView.OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e) in D:\Documents\Dev\ezcollector\solution\ObjectListView\ObjectListView.cs:line 7350
 ....
```

However this yields a NullReferenceException.

The Book is a class that extends Drop and this method is called on an ObjectListView when a selection change occurs.

Can anybody help me out here?

Cheers,

Comment: exactly which instruction yields the exception?

Comment: -1 Take time to try and troubleshoot NPE/NRE's first. A NRE could be generated from almost all of those lines -- as such the question as it is now is almost useless. Part of programming is to systematically isolate a problem, preferably with a debugger, but it's also possible with divide-and-conquer commenting, explicit null checks, and/or "trace print" statements. At the very least, please include the *top* of a stack-trace in such questions.

Comment: Done. Posted the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide the template and a minimal and reproducable test case.

Edit:
I think the problem is when accessing a null indexed property (like an IList). I've got a fix on my github fork which will be pushed to the main branch as well.

Comment: Hey, thank you for that. The template is some basic HTML with just one test tag called {{book.Title}}. In Book, there are many properties, if you want you can have a look at Book's definition here: http://ezcollector.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ezcollector/trunk/solution/Collect-It-All.Entities/Book.cs?revision=113&view=markup

Comment: Some of these properties might actually be "null" when passed to the Renderer, if this is an issue we can fix that of course. Just let me know ok ?

Comment: null properties have been ok for a long time, the issue I fixed was related to null indexed properties. The fix is on the main github repository, so you can now download the latest sources.
Looking at the Book's definition, could it be a problem with UUID property getter?

Comment: I removed the UUID from the Book definition and it still goes into a NullReferenceException. Not sure what to do at this point anymore :(

Comment: I've tried with the same Book class and the white template, here everything works as expected. I also tried downloading the solution from sf, but it does not compile. I suggest you to download the latest sources via GIT, add the project to your solution and step into DotLiquid sources. As I initially proposed, a minimal and reproducable test case is the way to go, otherwise I find it very difficult to provide you the support you need.

Comment: Hey. The solution from SF probably does not compile because you need a custom App.config. We can exchange that file if we further require. I installed GIT and will try to go into it. The thing is that using Unit Tests the think works, even with Books. But on the solution it goes bad. In http://ezcollector.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ezcollector/trunk/solution/Collect-It-All/CIA_Main.cs?revision=113&view=markup on Line 264, we use the method that gives the Error. It is an event fired by an ObjectListView when a selection changes.

Comment: Trefex, if your unit tests works then you are not unit testing your application the way you should.
Anyway, if you can't provide the smallest possible example to debug, then I have no more time to spend trying to compile or debug an entire solution.
I'm very glad to help and provide support for DotLiquid, but as you may understand, you should first try to provide us what we need to support you.

Comment: I fully understand your point. And the Unit Test is working, as you can see here http://ezcollector.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ezcollector/trunk/solution/Collect-It-All.UnitTests/DotLiquidTest.cs?revision=113&view=markup  I really don't see what's wrong with the way this Unit Test is done. Anyhow, I believe the bug is in the GUI part and it's of course our task to debug that part. I'll try to get you as much information as possible, and will try to cut down the solution to its bare parts. It's just very weird error since it's launched from DotLiquid.

Comment: in Variable.cs on Line 80 "object output = context[Name]" that's where the Exception is thrown when DotLiquid is trying to render the DotLiquid variable "book.Title". Can I provide you with more information like content of variables at this point?

Comment: In that case the exception is thrown when attempting variable resolution. That's very strange, I feel like a property getter is throwing the Exception. You should try to cut down the Book's definition to just a couple of simple properties to see which one is causing this issue. Please let me know.

Comment: Hi, I'll get back to you soon. Thank you for your tips.

Comment: Hi petrhaus. After long time I decided to try again with v 1.5 but I still get the exact same error. In fact the Unit Test works using the same Book class and everything, but as soon as I'm in the application, I can this fatal crash. Is there any way you can help me out?